# How to remove header space on ComboBox in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-phone-8.1, stackpanel

I'm trying to line up a TextBox and a ComboBox inside of a StackPanel, but the ComboBox seems to have some extra space at the top of it that I can't get rid of.

How can I get these two controls to align with each other properly?

[image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBox  IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Gray"               
        Text="{Binding ZoneName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
        PlaceholderText="YourCompany"/>
    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0"                      
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DomainChoices}"
         SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDomainChoice, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    SelectedValuePath="{Binding id}" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="{Binding text}"
                      Foreground="Black" Width="200">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can't you just set the margin of the ComboBox to something like "0,-5,0,0"

Comment: I could, but I'd rather eliminate what is introducing the extra space, instead of just shifting the entire control upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take a look at *ComboBox's* style then you will find that `<Border x:Name="ShortListOuterBorder" ....` has a *Margin* with value of `Margin="{ThemeResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"`. This resource is defined in the style above:

```xml
<Thickness x:Key="PhoneTouchTargetOverhang">0,9.5</Thickness>
```

You can easily define your own style in which you can change the above value, or change margin of the *Border*. You can also try to set the margin of your *ComboBox* to `0,-9.5,0,0` without applying the style.

Comment: Can you be more specific how I can override the value for Border Margin? I suppose I want to set it to 0,0 instead of 0,9.5.. I want to avoid workarounds like setting ComboBox margin to 0, -9.5 because I'd rather fix the root problem which is the border margin. Thanks.

Comment: @iupchris10 Open designer window (the one with preview of your page), right click on your *ComboBox* -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy. This should put the default style to your page's resources. Edit there the defined resource, then apply the style to the combobox (if you edit this way, VS should do it automatically).